# Can someone suggest a jQuery plugin for a smooth horizontal scrolling image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, smooth-scrolling

I have used Smooth div scroll by Thomas Kahn and it is exactly what I'm looking for, but there is a bug that I can't figure out. When I have the mousewheel scroll and touch scroll enabled at the same time, it is no longer smooth and skips around.  I don't think this plugin is still supported.

Any suggestions?   Thanks!

Comment: Jquery, smooth. Choose one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap instead of jquery. Bootstrap components are much more good.